# Python - BaseHTTPServer keep alive does not work

Tags: python, basehttpserver

I have the following code for a simple BaseHTTPServer based server.

```
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    #Handler for the GET requests
    def do_GET(self):
        # Parse the query_str
        query_str = self.path.strip().lower()
        if query_str.startswith("/download?"):
            query_str = query_str[10:]
            opts = urlparse.parse_qs(query_str)

            # Send the html message and download file
            self.protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header("Content-type", 'text/html')
            self.send_header("Content-length", 1)
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write("0")

            # Some code to do some processing
            # ...
            # -----------

            self.wfile.write("1")
```

I was expecting the HTML page to show "1", but it shows "0". How can I update the response through keep alive?

Answer (score 12):

I believe you are setting **self.protocol_version** to 'HTTP/1.1' too late.  You are doing it in your do_GET() method, at which point your request handler has already been instantiated, and the server has already inspected that instance's protocol_version property.

Better to set it on the class:

```
class myHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    protocol_version = 'HTTP/1.1'
```

Comment: Upvoting this for visibility. This was my exact issue, trying to set the protocol version in the GET() method does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if you want the 1 to be sent, you need to set your content-length to 2 or remove it entirely. The 1 is not going to overwrite the 0, so you will see 01.

Comment: doog's response looks right to me...  You might be able to self.wfile.seek(-1) to change it..   Be careful of character encodings and string lengths if you do this though.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for the answer. I want the page to display a 1 as soon as the processing finishes. Initially, I want it to display 0. If I set content length 2, it displays 01 only after the processing finishes.

Comment: I'm not aware of any way to do that using HTTP. It's possible you could accomplish your goal with redirects but it would require significantly more complex code. I can almost guarantee that the actual problem you are trying to solve has been solved using an alternate technique, but I don't think there is a way to overwrite data in a single HTTP response.

Answer (score 0):

https://docs.python.org/2/library/basehttpserver.html

**protocol_version**

This specifies the HTTP protocol version used in responses. If set to 'HTTP/1.1', the server will permit HTTP persistent connections; however, your server must then include an accurate Content-Length header (using send_header()) in all of its responses to clients. For backwards compatibility, the setting defaults to 'HTTP/1.0'.

Answer (score 0):

I faced same question. I tried set protocol_version in my do_METHOD() function which doesn't work.
My code look like this.

```
def _handle(self, method):
    self.protocol_version = "HTTP/1.1"
    # some code here

def do_GET(self):
    self._handle("GET")
```

I used ss and tcpdump to detect network and finally find server will reset connection after send response although it use http/1.1.

So I try set protocol_version just under my class which inherited from standard library class and it works. Because of cost of time, I don't dive into source code. Hope it works for others.